# Django is ignoring a field item for a Model with a fresh DB

Tags: python, sql, django

I've completely wiped all my database tables in order to add a new field to a model since wiping SQL tables clean is the fastest way to do so without going the '[south](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)' route when the SQL data only contains dummy data for testing purposes.

So here's my Model:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    uid = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='The student name.')
    resume = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_resume_name)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country)
    prim_interest = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='Maximum 250 characters.')
    sec_interest = models.CharField(max_length=250, help_text='Maximum 250 characters.')
    cellphone = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    email_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    thumbnail = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

and the last field that I've added called '`thumbnail`' is not being created by Django when I call syncdb right after deleting all my tables.

My method of completely wiping the tables has always worked no matter what drastic changes are applied to `models.py` and suddenly this is not the case for this instance. I could show you more code snippets but I have no clue where else in the Django project has a direct effect on generating models.

What could be causing syncdb to be refusing to write this new field 'thumbnail' to the Student table in the DB?

Comment: Are you using south for this app? I don't know what you mean by _my method of completely wiping the tables has always worked_ but the proper way to do it is to simply `python manage.py dbshell < python manage.py sqlclear yourappname`

Comment: if you only want to use syncdb, you can delete the file created for your db. I think it is called sqlite3.db. Delete it and then use again syncdb. Should work

Comment: Have a look at the sql query that is generated by syncdb. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Could be That south is interfering. You habe no migrations waiting. If I remember well syncdb dos not create tables That south is scheduled to create.

Why not make a south migrate after your syncdb?